# Grant access on Secondary but not on primary in SQL Server logshipping

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, log-shipping

I have a strange situation wherein users need permission on log shipped DB  on secondary server but not on primary. The problem is, the login has access on many other DBs on primary server apart from log shipped DB and that needs to be maintained. My environment is SQL Server 2012 EE.

Is it possible to achieve this?

As a workaround what I have tried is granting temporary access on my primary DB just before the backup log-shipping starts and once the backup completes I have added a step to remove it. But the issue with this workaround is, the users can still access the primary log shipped DB when I try to grant them access just before the log backup. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: I have already tried that but it does not work because CREATE USER...WITHOUT LOGIN creates a SID that is over 16 bytes. CREATE LOGIN requires a 16 byte GUID so the longer SID value is not compatible with the SID parameter of CREATE LOGIN.

Answer (score 1):

> On Primary

- Create a new Login `[testLogin]` and a new User `[testUser]` with the requiered rights and roles:

  ```
  USE [master]
  GO
  CREATE LOGIN [testLogin] WITH PASSWORD=N'test123'
      , DEFAULT_DATABASE=[Test], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF;
  GO
  USE [Test]
  GO
  CREATE USER [testUser] FOR LOGIN [testLogin];
  GO
  USE [Test]
  GO
  ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [testUser];
  GO
  ```

These login and user must not exist and be different from your current login and user.

- Once `[testUser]` is available on Secondary, remove `[testLogin]` from Primary:

  ```
  USE [master]
  GO
  DROP LOGIN [testLogin];
  ```

> Other option on Primary

- Remove the orignal Login

You must plan your update if you have to remove login for a short time and make sure you disconnect them first.

- Create a new Login with the same name

  ```
  CREATE LOGIN...
  ```
- Link Orphan users to the newly created Login for all DBs except the log shipped DB:

  ```
  USE [DB1]
  GO
  sp_change_users_login @Action='update_one'
      , @UserNamePattern='testUser'
      , @LoginName='testLogin';
  ```

> On Secondary `[testLogin]`:

- Create a new login `[testLogin]`:

  ```
  USE [master]
  GO
  CREATE LOGIN [testLogin] WITH PASSWORD=N'test123'
       , DEFAULT_DATABASE=[Test], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF;
  GO
  ```
- Link the orphan user `[testUser]` (shipped from Primary) to the new login `[testLogin]`:

  ```
  USE [Test]
  GO
  sp_change_users_login @Action='update_one'
      , @UserNamePattern='testUser'
      , @LoginName='testLogin';
  ```

Comment: As said, this works only when users don't have access to any other DBs on primary apart from log-shipped DBs. In my case this won't work as users have access on other DBs as well apart from log-shipped DBs. If I remove the login it will remove access for all DBs on primary. If I don't drop login and only drop user it will remove access from secondary DB as well.

Comment: you missed this line: If [testLogin] is still needeed on Primary, don't remove it... Have you tried it before saying it does not work and can you explain which part does not work?

Comment: Yes but if I keep it as it is it will give access to my primary log-shipped DB which I don't want. Also if I drop only user and not login the subsequent log backups will pick that command and it will drop from secondary as well.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to create a new login or AD group

Comment: I was thinking in that direction. i.e. to have separate login for log-shipped DBs.

Comment: That should work i think. But that has a problem too. What if users are already logged in?